# Comparing two variables within HTML in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

This is my **HTML code** :

```
{% for divida in Contrato %}
    {% for empresa in Empresa %}
        <li> 
            {{empresa.cnpj}} | {{divida.cnpj}}  |
            {% if empresa.cnpj == divida.cnpj %}
             True
            {% else %}
             False
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my **result**:

```
1. 52136308000162 | 72718870000101 | False
2. 05574445000107 | 72718870000101 | False
3. 72718870000101 | 72718870000101 | False
4. 52136308000162 | 05574445000107 | False
5. 05574445000107 | 05574445000107 | False
6. 72718870000101 | 05574445000107 | False
7. 52136308000162 | 52136308000162 | False
8. 05574445000107 | 52136308000162 | False
9. 72718870000101 | 52136308000162 | False
```

Lines 3, 5 and 7 should be True..

What am I missing?

Model for Empresa:

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=14, primary_key=True)    

    def __str__(self):
    return self.cnpj
```

Model for Contrato:

```
class Contrato(models.Model):
    contrato = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    cnpj = models.ForeignKey('users_c2p.Empresa', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
```

Comment: Please show the models. What are those `cnpj` fields?

Comment: They are like the social number for companies in Brazil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two values will never be equal. One is a string, and the other is an Empresa object.

You could fix this by comparing with the relevant field on the related object:

```
{% if empresa.cnpj == divida.cnpj.cnpj %}
```

but I cannot at all understand why you are doing this. The way to get the Empresa object related to a Contrado is, well, to do exactly what you already do: `divida.cnpj`. There is no need to separately loop through all Empresas until you find one that matches what you already have.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! That worked!
In fact I did this, because I need to retrieve an image from Empresa.

Comment: Now I realized, that I could call this: {{divida.cnpj.logo.url}} since from the beginning!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as an indication to future searchers that it solved your problem.

Comment: Sure, sorry! It really helped me!